# Open SDF database in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce

What do I need to open an SDF database in Visual Studio's 2008 Server Explorer?

I've installed Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 but Visual Studio seems to be unaffected by that installation.

Comment: I can connect to SQL Server compact DBs without having installed the SQL Server compact edition... Don't know what's wrong with your Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What edition do you use.

Mobile development is only supported on Visual Studio Professional Edition or higher.

If you installed your VS by default settings it should work "out of the box".